# "Text Box Vertical Alignment" to "Middle" for a selected rows in PowerPoint through vba macro

Tags: vba, powerpoint

[image]I would like to create a macro which will change  the "Vertical Alignment" to "Middle" of the selected rows/cells in a PowerPoint table. Can anyone pls help me with this.

Below example snapshot attached.

Below is the code. My code is perfectly working with the shape but could't work for the tables. pls assist.

```
ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange.TextFrame2.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorMiddle
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To approach a table you can not use the Shape Object, but need to use Tables.
You can also format only Cell by Cell so you need to run a loop through all Rows and Columns

-----edited-----

To use the selected cells you have to iterate through all cells and see if they are selected

```
Sub SelectedCells()
Dim oTbl As table
Dim iIdx As Integer
Dim iIdy As Integer
Set oTbl = ActiveWindow.Selection.ShapeRange(1).table
For iIdx = 1 To oTbl.Rows.Count
    For iIdy = 1 To oTbl.Columns.Count
        If oTbl.Cell(iIdx, iIdy).Selected Then
            With oTbl.Cell(iIdx, iIdy).Shape
            .TextFrame.VerticalAnchor = msoAnchorTop
            End With
        End If
    Next
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for this. But can we have any other way to apply "Top alignment" only on the selected rows/cell, not the entire table.